# Elementor icons not showing in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I used elementor icons (cart icons) for my WordPress website. it works earlier fine but right now once I logged in as admin then only the icon got displayed as soon as I logged out and view the website as a normal user, then the icon got disappeared and instead of it, some cross icon got displayed.

I tried to figure out the error and found the following things

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='elementor-icons-css'  href='https://lotusproshop.se/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/eicons/css/elementor-icons.min.css' media='all' />
```

This stylesheet load only when I logged in. One more thing: I observed that the cart icon does appear for some time and then changed into cross icon

I tried to paste all CSS of this stylesheet manually but it didn't work. Why does this error occur, and how can I fix this?

Comment: I think it would be nice if we could see your website so we could look for the code source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, a workaround for anyone that needs it is adding this code to functions.php:

```
function yourwebsite_icons() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'yourwebsite-icons',
        'https://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/eicons/css/elementor-icons.min.css',
        array(),
        '5.20.0'
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourwebsite_icons');
```